# displaying the top 3 rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In the school assignment I'm working on I need to display the 3 criminals with the most crimes. But I'm having a few problems

Here's the code I have so far, and its output:

```
`Select Last, First, Count(Crime_ID)
 From Criminals Natural Join crimes
 Group by Last, First, Criminal_ID
 order by Count(Crime_Id) Desc`

`LAST            FIRST      COUNT(CRIME_ID)
 --------------- ---------- ---------------
 Panner          Lee                      2 
 Sums            Tammy                    1 
 Statin          Penny                    1 
 Dabber          Pat                      1 
 Mansville       Nancy                    1 
 Cat             Tommy                    1 
 Phelps          Sam                      1 
 Caulk           Dave                     1 
 Simon           Tim                      1 
 Pints           Reed                     1 
 Perry           Cart                     1 

 11 rows selected `
```

I've been toying around with ROWNUM, but when I include it in the SELECT it won't run because of my GROUP BY. But If you put ROWNUM in the GROUP BY it just separates everything back out.

I just want to display the top 3 with the most crimes, which is weird because only 1 guy has more than 1 crime. Theoretically, more criminals would be added to the Database, but these are the tables given in the assignment.

Comment: "Assignment", there is a reason you get the homework and the teacher does not directly submit it to stack overflow

Comment: add WHERE ROWNUM <=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
  from  
( Select Last, First, Count(Crime_ID)
 From Criminals Natural Join crimes
 Group by Last, First, Criminal_ID
 order by Count(Crime_Id) Desc ) 
 where ROWNUM <= 3;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands this is quite a low quality post. Please consider reading this before posting again. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer